# Average Filter with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to implement an Averaging filter with a 5x5 kernel, although there is a function within OpenCV for this, I need to do it without it. 
There is something wrong and I think that are the variables uchar, but I tried int, float and double and the image resulting it's not correct. I use an image with a padding of 7.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "filter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

cv::Mat filter::mean_filter(cv::Mat& image_in){
    int centro = 7;
    float total = 0.0;
    double window[25];
    double mean= 0.0;
    int final=0;
    int nlines, ncols;


    cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat::ones(5, 5, CV_32S);
    nlines=image_in.size().height;
    ncols=image_in.size().width;

    cv::Mat image_out = cv::Mat::zeros(nlines,ncols,CV_32S);

    for (unsigned int j=centro; j<nlines - centro; j++){
        for (unsigned int z=centro; z<ncols - centro; z++){
            window[0]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-2,z-2);
            window[1]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-1,z-2);
            window[2]=image_in.at<uchar>(j  ,z-2);
            window[3]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+1,z-2);
            window[4]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+2,z-2);
            window[5]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-2,z-1);
            window[6]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-1,z-1);
            window[7]=image_in.at<uchar>(j  ,z-1);
            window[8]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+1,z-1);
            window[9]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+2,z-1);
            window[10]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-2,z);
            window[11]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-1,z);
            window[12]=image_in.at<uchar>(j  ,z);
            window[13]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+1,z);
            window[14]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+2,z);
            window[15]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-2,z+2);
            window[16]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-1,z+2);
            window[17]=image_in.at<uchar>(j  ,z+2);
            window[18]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+1,z+2);
            window[19]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+2,z+2);
            window[20]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-2,z+1);
            window[21]=image_in.at<uchar>(j-1,z+1);
            window[22]=image_in.at<uchar>(j  ,z+1);
            window[23]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+1,z+1);
            window[24]=image_in.at<uchar>(j+2,z+1);
            mean=0.0;
            final=0;

            for (unsigned int k=0; k<25; k++){      
                mean+=window[k];    
            }
            mean=mean/25;   
            final=round(mean);
            image_out.at<int>(j,z)=final;
        }
    }
return image_out;
}
```

Comment: Is the output image not being displayed correctly or the output values are incorrect?

Comment: The output values are incorrect

Comment: the easiest way would be to do a kernel with `1/(kernel_rows*kernelcols)` and then use the filter2D from OpenCV. The uchar will be only int IF your image_in is type CV_32S, if it is loaded with `imread` usually it will be CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC1 which is color or greyscale which will be type cv::Vec3b or uchar... you should say what type of matrix or how are you loading the image that you pass to the function

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a bit and have a working solution. It is a quite primitiv approach but it works.

Possible improvements could be to reuse some of the already accumulated pixel-values by tracking which pixels leave the kernel area and which pixels enter it.
Another possibility for improvement is to parallelise the loop over the image.

```
cv::Mat mean_filter(cv::Mat& image_in, int kernel)
{
  // Make sure you get a grayscale image.
  assert(image_in.type() == CV_8UC1);
  // Make sure your kernel is an uneven number
  assert(kernel % 2 == 1);
  // Make sure your kernel is bigger than 1
  assert(kernel >= 1);

  // for padding calculate the border needed
  int padding = (kernel - 1) / 2;

  int mean = 0.0;
  int final = 0;
  int nlines, ncols;
  cv::Mat img_temp;

  nlines = image_in.size().height;
  ncols = image_in.size().width;

  // Make propper padding. Here it is done with 0. Padding describes the adding of a border to the image in order to avoid a cropping by applying a filter-mask.
  copyMakeBorder(image_in, img_temp, padding, padding, padding, padding, BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);

  // allocate the output image as grayscale as the input is grayscale as well
  cv::Mat image_out = cv::Mat::zeros(nlines, ncols, CV_8UC1);

  // loop over whole image
  for (unsigned int j = padding; j<nlines + padding; j++){
    for (unsigned int z = padding; z<ncols + padding; z++){
      mean = 0.0;
      // loop over kernel area
      for (int x = -padding; x <= padding; x++){
        for (int y = -padding; y <= padding; y++){
          // accumulate all pixel-values
          mean += img_temp.at<uchar>(j + x, z + y);
        }
      }

      mean = mean / (kernel * kernel);
      final = round(mean);
      // cast result to uchar and set pixel in output image
      image_out.at<uchar>(j - padding, z - padding) = (uchar)final;
    }
  }

  return image_out;
}
```